# how to remove register and login form routes and leave everything else?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I need to remove the routes that lead to login and registeration form but I want leave everything as it is (verify email, reset password) would you tell me how to do this kindly?

Comment: Why would you need verify email and reset password? They are only used for registration and login (to my best of knowledge)

Comment: @UdoE. I have implemented ajax login and register and everything work fine though I need to remove the routes of default forms only.

Comment: @UdoE. you suggest deleting view files of registration form and login form? or what exactly?

Comment: Yes. You may also remove `showLoginForm()` and `showRegistrationForm()` from the appropriate controllers. But you may still need several other functions in these controller. For instance `validator()` and `create()`

Comment: Yes you can actually delete some routes you do not need. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ever run this command to generate the authentication files

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and you no longer need the files for the reason that you are doing login and registration using ajax, then you may have to remove the views associated with the files and remove some routes in the associated controllers that you do not need.

For instance, if you do not need the login and registration forms and the associated routes, you can follow the outlined steps below to remove them.

If you are in doubt of the routes that you need, first run this artisan command:

```
PHP artisan route:list
```

to see the details of the available routes and note the ones you need.

Thereafter, delete the `auth` route definition in `routes/web.php`

```
Auth:routes();
```

and declare the routes you need explicitly. In your case you should need post routes for registration/login and also the email verification routes:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::post('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verfy')->name('verification.verify');
```

Next, remove the views contained in the following **default** locations

```
resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
```

and

```
resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
```

These are the views for the respective forms.

Then remove `showLoginForm()` and `showRegistrationForm()` from

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginContoller.php
```

and

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 8 and this is how you can achieve it

```
Auth::routes([

  'register' => false, // Register Routes...

  'login' => false, // Login Routes...
]);
```